# Class returns integer instead of object while trying to get column data

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo

Just getting into OOP, and changing from mysql queries to PDO. I am trying to create a class that will return the column names and meta data for a table. This is so I can output copy/paste data for all the tables I use. I have used such a tool, based on the mysql extension, for ages and it spits out variants such as complete SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE queries. Amongst other things I now want to add DECLARE listings for Stored Procedures - so getting meta data like type and length are essential. With about 150 tables across two schemas, such automation is essential.

With uncertainty about the reliability of getColumnMeta I hunted for code and found what looked good in a [Sitepoint answer](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?497257-PDO-getColumnMeta-bug&s=e411c1bc22c0dbdbc365f3ce2b95f69e&p=3510380#post3510380). I have attempted to wrap it in a class and mimic its original context but I am simply getting a number 1 when I try to echo or print_r the response. I have also had 'not an object' error messages while trying solutions.

This is the calling code

```
$db_host="localhost";
$db_username='root';
$db_pass='';
$db_name='mydatabase';
try{
    $db= new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT=>false));
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
}
catch(PDOException $e){echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage()."<br />"; die(); }
include 'ColMetaData.php';   //the file containing the class for getting a column listing for each table
$coldat= new supplyColumnMeta($db);
$tablemet=$coldat->getColumnMeta('groups');   // a manual insertion of a table name for testing
echo $tablemet;
```

And this is the class that sits in the include file
    class supplyColumnMeta{
        public function __construct($db){
            $this->db=$db;

```
    }
    /**
        *    Automatically get column metadata
    */
    public function getColumnMeta($table)
    {$this->tableName=$table;
        // Clear any previous column/field info
        $this->_fields = array();
        $this->_fieldMeta = array();
        $this->_primaryKey = NULL;

        // Automatically retrieve column information if column info not specified
        if(count($this->_fields) == 0 || count($this->_fieldMeta) == 0)
        {
            // Fetch all columns and store in $this->fields
            $columns = $this->db->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $this->tableName, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach($columns as $key => $col)
            {
                // Insert into fields array
                $colname = $col['Field'];
                $this->_fields[$colname] = $col;
                if($col['Key'] == "PRI" && empty($this->_primaryKey)) {
                    $this->_primaryKey = $colname;
                }

                // Set field types
                $colType = $this->parseColumnType($col['Type']);
                $this->_fieldMeta[$colname] = $colType;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    protected function parseColumnType($colType)
    {
        $colInfo = array();
        $colParts = explode(" ", $colType);
        if($fparen = strpos($colParts[0], "("))
        {
            $colInfo['type'] = substr($colParts[0], 0, $fparen);
            $colInfo['pdoType'] = '';
            $colInfo['length']  = str_replace(")", "", substr($colParts[0], $fparen+1));
            $colInfo['attributes'] = isset($colParts[1]) ? $colParts[1] : NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            $colInfo['type'] = $colParts[0];
        }   
        // PDO Bind types
        $pdoType = '';
        foreach($this->_pdoBindTypes as $pKey => $pType)
        {
            if(strpos(' '.strtolower($colInfo['type']).' ', $pKey)) {
                $colInfo['pdoType'] = $pType;
                break;
                } else {
                $colInfo['pdoType'] = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }       
        return $colInfo;
    }
    /**
        *    Will attempt to bind columns with datatypes based on parts of the column type name
        *    Any part of the name below will be picked up and converted unless otherwise sepcified
        *     Example: 'VARCHAR' columns have 'CHAR' in them, so 'char' => PDO::PARAM_STR will convert
        *    all columns of that type to be bound as PDO::PARAM_STR
        *    If there is no specification for a column type, column will be bound as PDO::PARAM_STR
    */
    protected $_pdoBindTypes = array(
    'char' => PDO::PARAM_STR,
    'int' => PDO::PARAM_INT,
    'bool' => PDO::PARAM_BOOL,
    'date' => PDO::PARAM_STR,
    'time' => PDO::PARAM_INT,
    'text' => PDO::PARAM_STR,
    'blob' => PDO::PARAM_LOB,
    'binary' => PDO::PARAM_LOB
    );  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem:

```
public function getColumnMeta($table)
{
    $this->tableName=$table;
    // Clear any previous column/field info
    $this->_fields = array();
    $this->_fieldMeta = array();
    $this->_primaryKey = NULL;

    // Automatically retrieve column information if column info not specified
    if(count($this->_fields) == 0 || count($this->_fieldMeta) == 0)
    {
        // Fetch all columns and store in $this->fields
        $columns = $this->db->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $this->tableName, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach($columns as $key => $col)
        {
            // Insert into fields array
            $colname = $col['Field'];
            $this->_fields[$colname] = $col;
            if($col['Key'] == "PRI" && empty($this->_primaryKey)) {
                $this->_primaryKey = $colname;
            }

            // Set field types
            $colType = $this->parseColumnType($col['Type']);
            $this->_fieldMeta[$colname] = $colType;
        }
    }
    return true;//<<--- not returning an object/array!
}
```

Your `getColumnMeta` method returns a boolean, `true`. The string representation of this value is, of course, 1. If you want this method to return all of the meta-data, change the return statement to something like:

```
    return array(
        'fields'  => $this->_fields,
        'meta'    => $this->_fieldMeta,
        'primary' => $this->_primaryKey
    );
```

There are some other issues with your code, too, but seeing as this is *not* codereview.stackexchange, I'm not going to go into too much details. I will say this, though: Please, try to follow the coding standards that most major players adhere to: these standards can be found here: [PHP-FIG](http://www.php-fig.org).

Oh, and if you want to *show* the meta-data, don't `echo` them, but rather `var_dump` or `print_r` them, seeing as you return an array or an object.
Or at least `echo json_encode($instance->getColumnMeta($table));` to get a correct string representation of the returned value(s).